# GitHub pages: Bad references in custom domain

Tags: dns, github-pages

I have a project running well in **GitHub pages** (`myusername.github.io/projectname`) and I want to link to a **custom domain** (`www.mydomain.com`).

I followed these steps:

- 1) I created a `CNAME` in the gh-pages branch with the domain `www.mydomain.com`.
- 2) I created a `www` subdomain and a `CNAME` to `myusername.github.io`

But always my problem is the same... Is trying to reference all the images, scripts and styles to `www.mydomain.com/projectname/` when are located in the root `www.mydomain.com` ... And the project is not loading well.

Somebody have the same issue? How can I fix it?

*Thank you so much!*

Comment: Could you add the Github repo URL?

Comment: www.ourparkbcn.com is the custom domain and the repo is this one: https://github.com/aralroca/ourparkbcn  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index.html` (`gh-pages` branch), you can change

```
<base href="/ourparkbcn/">
```

to

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) !!